# How to search a listbox (bound to a dictionary) through a text field

Tags: .net, dictionary, listbox

I wonder if some one can help me understand Dictionary's and what happens when you unbound them.

I have a listbox that contains numerous music tracks and these are read from a file. The file information is the location of the mp3 music file. The data is split into 2 values. The songTitle and the SongLocation. These are stored in my MusicDictionary as key and Value and all works fine.

I would now like to be able to search the listbox via a textfield for favourite songs, and would like the listbox to display the found items, if any. From what I understand, so far is that I have to unbind the listbox and create a new one for the found items to be displayed.

So far I have had numerous errors based on the code below

System.ArgumentException: 'Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.'

Here is the code I am trying to figure out

```
Private Sub TextBoxSearchMusic_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBoxSearchMusic.TextChanged
    'ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    For Each item As String In MusicDictionary.Keys
        If item.StartsWith(TextBoxSearchMusic.Text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(item)
        End If
        ListBox1.DataSource = ListBox1.Items
    Next
End Sub
```

If someone can figure out what I am doing wrong, I would appreciate any asistance.

So, the question is if I unbind the music dictionary datasource from the listbox and create a new temporary founditems for the listbox to display. Will I lose my original data? And if not am I able to bind to it again?

Thank you

(EDIT)

I have managed to get the code to stop crashing but my listbox is not being populated, this is my updated code.

```
       ListBox1.DataSource = Nothing
    
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()

    For Each item As String In allItems
        If item.Contains(TextBoxSearchMusic.Text) Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(item)
        End If
    Next
    ListBox1.DataSource = ListBox1.Items
    'ListBox1.DisplayMember.
```

Answer (score 0):

This took way more time than I thought, but I managed to solve the issue.

```
ListBox1.DataSource = Nothing 'Unbinds the existing datasource
        ListBox1.Items.Clear() 'Clears the listbox of any content
        Dim newDictionary = MusicDictionary.Where(Function(pair) pair.Key.Contains(TextBoxSearchMusic.Text)).ToDictionary(Function(pair) pair.Key, Function(pair) pair.Value) 'Filters the Music Dictionary through the TextBoxSearchMusic field and adds the result to the newDictionary 
        For i = 0 To newDictionary .Count - 1 'Loop through the newDictionary 
            ListBox1.Items.Add(newDictionary.Keys(i) & newDictionary.Values(i))  'Adds all the found Items to the newDictionary 
        Next
        ListBox1.DataSource = New BindingSource(newDictionary, Nothing) 'Binds the newDictionary to the listbox
        ListBox1.DisplayMember = "Key" 'Displays only the Key in the listbox
```

I hope the above will be able to help someone in the future.